# 100% height of window with inner div scrolling

Tags: html, css, layout

I've been banging my head against the wall really hard for the past couple of hours to figure out a way to achieve the layout I'd like for a webapp. And my head hurts.

Basically what I need is to have a full window layout (full width, full height, no scrolling - ever). 100% of width and height should be covered using two different horizontal boxes (you can see them as rows).

- The height of the first box/row can be variable (see it as a header for the page)
- The one below should occupy what's left of the space, without ever going further than 100% of the window, hence without ever showing a scrollbar.

Now what's a bit more tricky is that within the second box/row, I want content to be displayed with an inner vertical scrolling. Imagine the second box/row contains a list of items, in case of very few items, the bottom part of the box/row should stop right after the content. In case of many items, the box/row should expand right until it hits 100% of the window height (which is basically 100% of the windows - the height occupied by the first box/row). The rest of the content should be visible through scrolling within the second box/row.

Am I making any sense?

Regarding the code, I'm not going to copy/paste the desastrous thing I've pulled together because I'd rather start from a blank page.

This is what I tried:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="wrapper">
      <div class="box">Header</div>
      <div class="box">Content <ul><li>...</li>(x1000)</ul></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The reason why I use a "box" class is because both boxes/rows should show the same appearence in terms of backgrounds, margins, shadows, etc.

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

#wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  left: 15px;
  right: 15px;
  top: 15px;
  bottom: 15px;
}
```

For the rest, I've just tried (and failed so far) to manipulate the `.box` elements by adding hazardously `overflow: hidden; overflow-y: scroll; height: 100%; max-height: 100%; min-height: 100%;` etc.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Any chance you can add your code to a fiddle?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is because CSS has long been crappy about auto-adjusting height to available space.

The solution is to use a wrapper that's set to `position: absolute` and tied to the top, left, right, and bottom edges of the viewport. With this, the browser will auto adjust the height of the element, and if you have a content div inside with `height: 100%` it'll always fill that space.

Setting `overflow-y: scroll` on the wrapper will allow the content to scroll if it becomes too long:

http://codepen.io/helion3/pen/jwbcx

Site headers are usually not variable in height. If you're defining the site header using percentages, and if you don't need to support IE<8 then you can use percentages safely with `box-sizing: border-box` to achieve the same.

Comment: For my understanding, does it mean I shouldn't ever specify a height of 100%? I mean, defining `position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0` is basically the same as defining `height: 100%`? Same applies for width? Let's say I want a small margin all around the wrapper, can I simply specify `position: absolute; top: 15; bottom; 15`?

Comment: You would specify the `height: 100%` for the content div *inside* the absolute-positioned wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this should do the trick.

If you adjust the height of `.header` make it is equal to the `top:` position of `.content`

## CSS:

```
html, body {
  margin: 0;
}

.header {
  height: 150px;

  background: #0080ff; // (Unnecessary, this is set to help you see the header div)
}

.content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 150px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  overflow: auto;

  background: #ff8000; // (Unnecessary, this is set to help you see the content div)
}
```

## HTML:

```
<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div class="box header">Header</div>
    <div class="box content">Content</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks- this is almost exactly what I was looking for. An additional side question though: with the proposed solution, the `box content` is fully scrollable. In my case, I'd like that `box` to have e.g. a title and a short description - which should remain visible at all times too; what shall I do to only have e.g. a `<p>` or `<div>` scrollable, within the `box content`?

In this case it means the structure would be `body > #wrapper > box.content > p.scrollable`.

Comment: Not quite sure if I understand you. You don't want the .content scrollable but instead a div inside of .content that is scrollable? Could you draw up like an image that kind of shows the functionality you're referring to?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/w6D4C/1/)? I replaced `class="box"` with `id`s, but it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Consider following things:

- No need to have the "absolute" positioned div (#wrapper in your example)
- Create 2 box div same like you have created in your example (.box)
- Second box should have "overflow:auto" style property
- Calculate the height of header and full display area's height with javascript
- Calculate the remaining height and assign this value as height, min-height and max-height for the second box. That's it.

You can check the solution here:
http://webnflash.com/temp/occupyAvailableHeight.htm